# OpenBSD 6.7 Wireguard instructions fail

Tags: network-interface, openssl, openbsd, bsd, wireguard

Wireguard setup instructions don't work for me on my OpenBSD 6.7 machine:

```
$ uname -a
OpenBSD foobar 6.7 GENERIC.MP#3 amd64
$ sysctl kern.version
kern.version=OpenBSD 6.7 (GENERIC.MP) #3: Thu Jul  9 07:21:14 MDT 2020
    root@syspatch-67-amd64.openbsd.org:/usr/src/sys/arch/amd64/compile/GENERIC.MP
```

I believe that my system *should* have the kernel-space Wireguard driver (i.e., `wg(4)`) due to the output above.

By default, there are no Wireguard interfaces:

```
$ ifconfig
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 32768
    index 3 priority 0 llprio 3
    groups: lo
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x3
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
vio0: flags=e48843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST,INET6_NOPRIVACY,AUTOCONF6,INET6_NOSOII,AUTOCONF4>     mtu 1500
    lladdr 56:00:02:f5:e5:fa
    index 1 priority 0 llprio 3
    groups: egress
    media: Ethernet autoselect
    status: active
    inet6 fe80::5400:2ff:fef5:e5fa%vio0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
    inet 149.28.165.216 netmask 0xfffffe00 broadcast 149.28.165.255
    inet6 2401:c080:1800:4463:5400:2ff:fef5:e5fa prefixlen 64 autoconf pltime 604596 vltime 2591796
enc0: flags=0<>
    index 2 priority 0 llprio 3
    groups: enc
    status: active
pflog0: flags=141<UP,RUNNING,PROMISC> mtu 33136
    index 4 priority 0 llprio 3
    groups: pflog
```

As there are also no man pages for Wireguard, I install `wireguard-tools`:

```
$ sudo pkg_add wireguard-tools
quirks-3.326 signed on 2020-09-09T17:39:55Z
wireguard-tools-1.0.20200319v0: ok
New and changed readme(s):
    /usr/local/share/doc/pkg-readmes/wireguard-tools
```

The man page for [`wg(4)`](https://man.openbsd.org/wg#EXAMPLES) provides these instructions for creating a Wireguard interface. This fails on my machine with:

```
$ ifconfig wg0 create wgport 111 wgkey `openssl rand -base64 32` rdomain 1
ifconfig: wgport: bad value
$ echo $?
1
$ sudo ifconfig
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 32768
    index 3 priority 0 llprio 3
    groups: lo
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x3
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
re0: flags=808843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST,AUTOCONF4> mtu 1500
    lladdr dc:4a:3e:d6:23:bd
    index 1 priority 0 llprio 3
    groups: egress
    media: Ethernet autoselect (100baseTX full-duplex)
    status: active
    inet 192.168.0.16 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
enc0: flags=0<>
    index 2 priority 0 llprio 3
    groups: enc
    status: active
pflog0: flags=141<UP,RUNNING,PROMISC> mtu 33136
    index 4 priority 0 llprio 3
    groups: pflog
wg0: flags=8082<BROADCAST,NOARP,MULTICAST> mtu 1420
    index 26 priority 0 llprio 3
    groups: wg
```

Clearly, the `wg0` interface is created, but the parameters are silently dropped (i.e., no private key, no port, and no `rdomain`).

Comment: was the ifconfig tool really updated along the kernel? eg: https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-cvs&m=159274202612788&w=2

Comment: http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/sbin/ifconfig/ifconfig.c?rev=1.422&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup vs. http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/sbin/ifconfig/ifconfig.c?only_with_tag=OPENBSD_6_7 . rev 1422 isn't here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't entirely clear on what version of the OS you are using.  Note that `wg` *wasn't* available on `6.7-release` and *isn't* available on `6.7-stable` (i.e., `-release` plus patches).  Your `uname` and `sysctl kern.version` suggests that you are using the latter.  `wg` *is* available on `-current`, and FWIW works fine for at least a month now (I tested your command on a machine running a snapshot from Aug 15 ).

However you have (apparently) partial support for `wg` on `ifconfig` but no `man` page for it, which indicates that the kernel isn't synced with userland, as @A.B already noted.

Since the system already appears not to be following `-stable`, having been partially upgraded with a `-current` kernel, if `wg` is an urgent need, my advice would be to bring it all up to date with `-current` using `sysupgrade -s` (don't forget to upgrade the packages as well).  Also, note that it shouldn't be long now before `6.8-release`, which will have native wireguard support, so if the urgency of having `wg` doesn't outweigh the advantages for running `-stable`, you might just wait a couple of weeks and upgrade to `6.8-release` when it comes out.

Comment: Thank you! You're correct, `sysupgrade -s` brought the system up-to-date with native Wireguard support and now the instructions I was following (https://xosc.org/wireguard.html) work!